# SWT Browser not loading

Tags: browser, swt

I would like to use SWT browser inside my java application.

I started with the demo source code available [here](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet128.java). The demo works as expected for all of the urls, except for the url "https://map.geo.sz.ch". It just displays loading along with processing symbol indefinitely.

While this page is loaded, there is a message on the eclipse console "Vector smash protection is enabled.".

Any idea what is happening with this url? is it an issue on the server side or client side?

I am testing it on Windows 10, JRE8u65x64, Eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1), IE11

Comment: If I try loading the page with the IDE's built-in web browser I get 'Security Warning' dialogs on Windows (create dummy HTML file, open with browser and paste the URL into the location filed, hit return). The workbench web browser also uses SWTs browser widget. I assume that this is the reason for what you see.

Comment: With Eclipse internal web browser, after accepting the security warning dialog the page loads as expected, however with the demo even after accepting the securing warning the page doesn't load.

Comment: Did you try to create the browser with `SWT.MOZILLA` or `SWT.WEBKIT` (if that's available on Windows) to see if it changes anything?

Comment: Looking at the page source, it seems that the actual page content is created through Javascript and HttpRequests. Maybe a script error prevents it from loading completely.

Comment: Yes it looks like that script is blocking, but it is strange it blocks only when using the SWT browser. And by the way, Eclipse internal browser uses different implementation, available at org.eclipse.ui.internal.browser.WebBrowserView.

Comment: In my environment (Win7, IE 11) the page doesn't show up, neither in the internal browser not in a standalone SWT browser snippet.

Comment: I don't see a 'different implementation'. In the end `WebBrowserView` as well as `WebBrowserEditor` use a `BrowserViewer` which encapsulates an SWT `Browser`widget.

Comment: I get similar error message sometimes while loading eclipse.org and the page doesn't load 100%. This doesn't happen always but on some refresh event.